# Unable to find 'struts.multipart.saveDir' property setting. Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2

While trying to upload the Image in struts2
the image is not uploading and showing following msg
 Unable to find `struts.multipart.saveDir` property setting. Defaulting to `javax.servlet.context.tempdir`

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify

```
struts.multipart.saveDir=
```

property in either struts.xml file as a constant entry or you need to specify that in struts.properties file choice is all yours.

```
struts.multipart.saveDir - The directory where the uploaded files will be placed. If this property is not set it defaults to javax.servlet.context.tempdir.
```

this is the case with your post since you have not specified the location by yourself so struts2 is picking up the temp location for file upload.

here is the link defining the details
[File Upload](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/File+Upload)

**edit**
in `struts.xml`

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="location of your choice" />
    ...
</struts>
```

Comment: Thankyou Umesh for answering but i am not getting how to put this code in struts.xml

Comment: @Quaternion: Thanks :) though i love such settings in property files kinda of addicted to that..but i think struts.xml is good place :)